# как работает это строка return a * power(a, n - 1)?

Tags: python

Есть функция которая возводит числов степень с помощью рекурсии
не могу понять как здесь работает рекурсия
Как питон перемножает эти все числа,когда в функции 2 аргумента??
Вот код:

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n != 1:
        return a * power(a, n - 1)
        
a = int(input())
n = int(input())

print(power(a, n))
```

Comment: попробуйте пошагово выполнить это на http://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загуглите рекурсия. А вкратце так:

```
return a * power(a, n - 1)
```

Bызывается `power(a, n - 1)`, значение на выходе умножается на a и возвращается. В свою очередь при вызове `power(a, n - 1)` происходит тоже самое, пока не будет достигнуто условие:

```
if n == 0:
    return 1
```

i.e.:

```
power(4, 3) = 4 * power(4, 2) = 4 * (4 * power(4, 1)) = 4 * (4 * (4 * power(4, 0))) = 4 * 4 * 4 * 1 = 4³ = 64
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119930/discussion-on-answer-by-victor-vosmottor-----return-a-powe).